# How to make cin in c++ not to break a line?

Tags: c++

Is there anyway to not break line after cin is entered.
e.g. now -

> Enter percent: 25
>
> %

I want:

> Enter percent: 25%

p.s. sorry for not showing code, forgot to add it. I hope this will be enough.

```
    cout << "Enter Percent:";
    cin >> perc;
    cout << "%";
```

Comment: mac os x mountain lion :D

Comment: A terminal is usually line-buffered. This enables the user to change mistakes until (s)he presses enter. As such you need to use operating system specific code. Also it's not clear what the user input should be: "25%" or only "25"?

Comment: how about showing some code??

Comment: what does this achieve....

Comment: flagged this question

Answer (score 1):

Cross platform solution:
`rlutil.h`
http://tapiov.net/rlutil/docs/HTML/files/rlutil-h.html#rlutil.locate

void locate(    int     x,
int     y   )

Comment: I would prefer not using header files

Comment: dont use c++ then -.-

Comment: i meant for now, as i am new to this I intend to do things as simple as i can.

Comment: can get any simpler than including a really simple to use Cross platform library... Command: g++ source.c library.c -o yourprogram.exe